# Plotting 3 different columns from a CSV file python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, sorting, plot

My goal is to use the sorted result data to plot "Month vs Mean Temp"  graph for each year on the same window.

I've sorted the first two columns that have the year and the month respectively and then saved the new sorted data into a file called `NewFile`, but I can't seem to get to a solution here, I used `csv` reader and now I'm using *numpy*,

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

csv1 = open('Data_5.1.csv')
data = np.array(list(csv.reader(csv1,delimiter=',').astype("string")

year = data[:,0]
month = data[:,1]
temp= data[:,3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(year, month, label='month/year')
ax.plot(year, temp, label='year/temp')

 plt.legend()
```

But it just throws an error saying:

```
File "<ipython-input-282-282e91df631f>", line 9
year = data[:,0]
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I will put two links to the files, the *Data_5.1* and the *NewFile* respectively

[Data_5.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uV_MET1sdhmvean1jUvrU4mwDszhfAFe)
[NewFile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fIbAteWDad4SHsVBnBw-kSz4_Ja_mY6C)

Comment: The indentation is way off, is that just because of the formatting here?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, it's because of the formatting; I tried to make it look easier on the eyes, it has the same error with or without those indents btw.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should use a context manager for that file. Also, is there any reason why you’re using NumPy over something like Pandas for this? If you are sticking with NumPy, why not use the functions that were designed for this, like `genfromtxt()`?

Answer (score 0):

1 - You didn't close brackets in line 6, hence you are getting the error in line 8.

2 - astype("string") is not needed in line 6.

I fixed your code, but you will have to complete the subplotting. Good luck!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
plt.style.use('ggplot')

csv1 = open('Data_5.1.csv')
data = np.array(list(csv.reader(csv1,delimiter=',')))



year = data[:,0]
mounth = data[:,1]
temp= data[:,3]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2) #This will create 4X4 subplots in one window

ax[0,0].plot(year, mounth, label='mounth/year') #This will plot in the 0,0 subplot
ax[0,1].plot(year, temp, label='year/temp') #This will plot in the 0,1 subplot
'''
For you to continue.
'''


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data is in a CSV file, and it's non-homogenous in type. Pandas is really the more appropriate tool for this.

I had to adapt your CSV slightly due to encoding errors, here is what it ended up looking like:

```
year,Month,Other Month,temperature_C
2003,Jan.,Some val,17.7
2004,Jan.,Some val,19.5
2005,Jan.,Some val,17.3
2006,Jan.,Some val,17.8
...
```

Here is a general sketch of what the code you shared could look like after the refactoring:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')

# csv1 = open('Data_5.1.csv')
# data = np.array(list(csv.reader(csv1,delimiter=',').astype("string")

df_1 = pd.read_csv('../resources/Data_5.1.csv', header=0, names=['year', 'month', 'some_col', 'temp'],
                   dtype={'some_col': str, 'temp': float, 'month': str, 'year': str})

year = df_1['year']
month = df_1['month']
temp = df_1['temp']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.plot(year, month, label='month/year')
ax.plot(year, temp, label='year/temp')
plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)